# invalid outside procedure Error In Access?? Looked at other questions on this site but still do not understand

Tags: vba, ms-access

My code in vba for access was working fine, I had procedures that I wrote for different events that all worked. Then when I went to give my combo boxes and text boxes an assigned row source and now nothing works. I get this invalid outside procedure error. So after hours of trouble shooting I ended up deleting the entire form and then rebuilding it and I still get the same error. So now I just working with one event just until I can get things figured out.

```
Public Sub cb_op1_AfterUpdate()

tb_LbrRate1.Value = DLookup("LaborRate", "tbloperationsType", "[operationsID] = cb_op1.value")

End Sub
```

This use to work but now it won't?? tb_LbrRate1.value is a text box and cb_op1.value is a combo box.

I have tried this too

```
Public Sub cb_op1_AfterUpdate()



End Sub
```

I left everything blank and I still get the error when I change a value in my combo box?? I just don't get it!!!! any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When is the error? On compilation or on run-time? What error is it? Number?

Comment: Try to compile the code and you will probably see the problem.

Comment: The error occurs when I have the form running and I am entering values and it goes to update. Also there is no error number

Comment: Can you do this: http://www.spreadsheet1.com/uploads/3/4/3/6/34364573/3641131_orig.png?538 and check what you get?

Comment: I compiled the code and found the error and now it works. I did't even know about compiling the code, just asked google.  I am learning the hard way. But I won't make that mistake again.  For other users with the same problem click on debug and then click compile code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this:

[image]

and check what you get?

This error in MS Access is usually because of code flying not between `Sub` and `End Sub`.